# starting new activity on click of buttons in a gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-gridview

I have a gridview and I'm setting a button adapter to it. It has 2 buttons and I want to set the Onclick listeners for these buttons.

```
 GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_table_select);
 gridview.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));
```

In the getView() method for my Gridview, I'm adding buttons as grid items. I'm also setting the onClick listener for the buttons.

```
 public View getView(int position,
                           final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  Button btn;

  if (convertView == null) {
   // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
   btn = new Button(mContext);
   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context , Main.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
   btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350, 65));
   btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
   btn.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

As you can see I'm setting the onClick for the buttons, and trying to start a new activity, but when I click on these buttons, nothing happens.
What should I correct?

Comment: Context context = v.getContext(); instead use mContext there you already have there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Context context = v.getContext();` instead use `mContext` there you already have there

```
    if (convertView == null) {
           // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
           btn = new Button(mContext);
           btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, //<-------------
Main.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

make your Activity class implement `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

and in oncreate() call

```
gv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
gv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and use onItemClick() to handle item click

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , Main.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your Context in the begining of your class, maybe in constructor if it's not your activity. You have already done. mContext. use it there instead of getting new context.

Answer (score 0):

Few corrections to your code..

```
public View getView(int position,
                    final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button btn = convertView;

    if (btn == null) {
       btn = new Button(mContext);
       btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Main.class)
              intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              mContext.startActivity(intent);
          }
       });
       btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350, 65));
       btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
       btn.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   }
   // set some text or do something
   ...
   return btn;
}
```